# jQuery button open list, list closed when clicked outside

Tags: jquery, button, menu

I know there are a dozen of question on this on SO, but none of them seem to work for me. What I am trying is the following code:

```
jQuery('.mybutton').click(function(){

  jQuery('.list').show().bind('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  jQuery('html').bind('click', function() {
    jQuery('.list').hide();
  });
});
```

The list item never opens. The html bind click is always fired.

Comment: Can we see the HTML maybe there is an issue there?

Comment: Is there a reason to use bind here, can you directly use click and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding the `click` to the `html` and `.list`, bind it globally, and check whether the current target is (a child of) a `.list` element.

```
jQuery('.mybutton').click(function(){
  jQuery(window).click(function(event) {
       var $elem = $(event.target)
       if($elem.hasClass('list') || $elem.parents('.list').length == 0) return;
       jQuery('.list').hide();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really be binding events on click like that. Try something like this instead.

```
jQuery('.mybutton').click(function(e){
  jQuery('.list').show();
   e.stopPropagation();
});

jQuery('body').click(function() {
  jQuery('.list').hide();
});

jQuery('.list').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I think the main problem is that you need a stopPropagation call in your mybutton click handler too.